# Can't compile anything, not sure why (puppy linux)

Tags: linux, compile, make, puppylinux

I'm stuck on linux for a while while I try to fix my normal computer functionality, and though I've reinstalled every dependency needed to compile, it seems as though I can't compile anything still.

I need to compile several programs, but it seems as though I don't have a "make" command

I used "find" and found 3 such scripts, but the contents were only:

```
/usr
/usr/bin
```

and it doesn't seem to me like they actually do anything.

(I pointed the terminal to them and ran them, but it spat out "/usr is a directory, /usr/bin is a directory")

When I do ./configure, the only error that shows up is

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Do I have a bad install of GCC? How do I repair my compiler to actually work properly?

(another aside, There are a few programs that I need to compile that don't seem to have proper configure scripts, how do I fix those? it says something about a hostname that wasn't specified)

Comment: Did you install 'make' ?  it's usually a separate package.  Does puppy linux have a 'build-essentials' or 'development tools' type of virtual package to pull in everything needed to compile?   Have you installed gcc?  Should install 'devx' it says here: http://puppy.b0x.me/wiki/doku.php?id=compile

Comment: oh I didn't even realize that existed... I'll install it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Make will not have anything to do with the message "C compiler cannot create executables" in your configure script. You need to look at the file `config.log` that is created by the configure script, and see what the `gcc` command line used is. See if your gcc can compile a program that does nothing with this command:

`echo 'int main(){}' | gcc -xc -`

If you get any errors, your gcc installation is almost certainly broken. If it simply creates a file called `a.out` in the current directory, you know that you at least have a working gcc installation, and that the problem is probably not gcc itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the devx package for your distro (you didn't say which version of Puppy you are using). This contains gcc plus lots of other stuff to help with programming and other things. You can usually find it in Puppy Package Manager